# jTemplates: html in variables

Tags: jquery, jtemplate

I'd like to include some html in a jTemplate variable - e.g.

```
<td class="numeric">{$T.total_price}</td>
```

Where total_price is:

```
"$12<span>.00</span>"
```

Is there any way I can get the span to show up as html?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it with:

```
$('#mhid')setTemplate(s, [], {filter_data: false});
```

Comment: +1 Thank you @EoghanM, this worked perfectly - substituting '***s***' above with the template name I was using. If I am honest, I don't find 'http://jtemplates.tpython.com' very good on the documentation side of things. Do you have any references for jTemplate? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem:

**Template:**

```
   <textarea id="pagination" style="display:none"><b>pagination</b></textarea>
```

If I call the template as:

```
$('').setTemplate($('pagination').html(),[],{filter_data: false});

$('').processTemplate();
```

Its not working. its displaying as:

```
<b>pagination</b>
```

If I call the same template by using setTemplateElement like:

```
$('').setTemplateElement('pagination');

$('').processTemplate();
```

Its working. its displaying as: **pagination**

Comment: I know this is an old post, but in my case it works perfectly with the solution that @EoghanM has given. My template was referenced by: `$('foobar').setTemplateElement("pagination", [], { filter_data: false });`. Note the textarea 'id' in quotes: "pagination", and not '$('pagination').html()' as you have above (you are missing a # here too BTW). Have a look at http://jtemplates.tpython.com in the FAQ page at the top. I hope this helps someone.