# Escaping strings in JTemplate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jtemplates

I have a JTemplate string that looks like this

```
<a class="add"  href="#" onclick="javascript:myfunction('{$T.Properties.Title}')" >
```

This code breaks when my parameter $T.Properties.Title is a string which contains a single quote character in it.

I could use a double quote character while passing my parameter value, but my code will then break for double quotes.

How do I escape the input string so that my code works for strings that have both single and double quotes in them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape quotes with backslashes when you create the object:

```
Properties = {Title: 'I\'m lovin\' my quotes'};
```

**EDIT :**

As per your comment:

> No control over the source, sadly. :( the JSON comes from a third
>   party site

You can either try using `setTemplate(s, [], {filter_params: true});`

which according to [the docs](http://jtemplates.tpython.com/doc/symbols/Template.html) is using escapeHTML - but I haven't tried and I'm not sure how it works.

See this question about escaping HTML with `filter_data`: [jtemplates-html-in-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721603/jtemplates-html-in-variables)

Or try escaping quotes after you receive the JSON object.
I believe in PHP you can use `json_encode` - see here: [json-parse-error-with-double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949604/json-parse-error-with-double-quotes)

Other solutions described here: [javascript-how-escape-quotes-in-a-var-to-pass-data-through-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031324/javascript-how-escape-quotes-in-a-var-to-pass-data-through-json)

Comment: No control over the source, sadly. :( the JSON comes from a third party site.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, finally what I did was escaped the quotes in java script.

Following is my code.

In Template:

```
$('#content').setParam('getUrl', getUrl);
```

In HTML; inside template.

```
href="{$P.getUrl($T.RESULTS.URL)}"
```

JS Method:

```
function(theLink){
  return theLink.replace(/\"/g, "%22");

  //If you want to escape all the characters use the following
  return escape((theLink))
}
```

Cheers..:)